# How to call a C++ API from C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop, pinvoke

I have a pretty big system implemented in C++ I need to interact with. The system has a pretty big API, a number of C++ DLLs. These DLLs export C++ classes, as opposed to a nice C style API. and I need to use them from a new C# project.

From what I know .NET has three ways of interacting with native software:

1. P/Invoke - which works only on C APIs
2. COM objects
3. C++/CLI

So the way I understand it, I have three approaches accordingly:

1. Writing a wrapper in C and calling it with P/Invoke. which seems way too much work.
2. Writing a wrapper with COM. which I don't know how to do, and unless it's insanely easy i'm reluctant to learn what seems to me - a dying technology .
3. Writing a wrapper in C++/CLI. which seems the least work, though still a lot.

My question:

1. First of all I would like to know why doesn't .NET allow me simply
   to use the C++ classes "as is"? I'm assuming it's a matter of memory
   management. and if it is I'm more than willing to write finalizers,
   and implementing IDisposable . From what I know C++ classes are just
   really fancy structs, and since P/Invoke supports structs, and functions
   that take structs as the first parameter, why not support
   classes?
2. Second, assuming I'm really lazy, and its a lot of boring, tedious,
   work, What would be the best way to use these DLL's? a possibility
   to call them directly from C# would be the best. If not then I'd
   love an automatic tool to produce the wrappers. Also, the DLLs might
   change, probably, just slightly but still, id rather not be forced
   to manually re-write wrappers.

For a really good answer, especially on the first part, or a good automatic tool, I'll reward a bounty...

Thank you

Comment: 1.  Because different DLL's have different calling conventions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120690/tool-for-creating-net-wrappers-for-a-com-dll

Comment: I think C++/CLI would be good. I don't exactly have experience doing this with C++ exports, though.

Comment: [Cxxi](https://github.com/mono/cxxi) sounds like what you want, but I'm not sure how usable it is yet.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ,  Its handled just fine in P/Invoke for C calling conventions, And the C++ system is using VC++ ...

Comment: Well, you have to tell it how to interact with the DLL somehow.  `extern` declarations seem as good a way to do that as any other.  .NET assemblies can be referenced directly because they already contain metadata that describes the entry points.

Comment: I'd imagine the main reason for not supporting C++ classes is because C++ does not have a standardized ABI. And no, C++ classes aren't *just fancy structs*. A given class might be using [virtual] multiple inheritance for example. The behind the scenes implementation of that is completely up to the discretion of the compiler vendor for example.

Comment: @RobertHarvey , I'm willing to tell it whatever it wants to know, I'm even willing to write, myself, a tool that will generate extern declarations. What i'm not willing to do, is writing a lot of wrapper code by hand. and wore **maintaining** it.

Comment: My searches of the Internet's tubes seem to be that it is easiest to write your own managed C++ to act as wrappers for the unmanaged C++. Check out this write up of the P/Invoke versus the bridging managed C++ DLL at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18032/How-to-Marshal-a-C-Class

Comment: StarPilot is correct, using C++/CLI as a "glue" language is the best option when you need to interface between .NET and native C++ code.

Comment: I suppose it also depends on the number of C++ classes. Why would you expose 1000 C++ classes to .NET as is? Most of the time, we expose a subset of the C++ classes, a "service-like" facade, and if you look at how Microsoft did it for GDI+ for example, they just exposed some of it using simple DLL Exports and build a new set of .NET style object in C#. I think its good to have a clean contract between the C++/unmanaged world and the .NET/managed world. Keeping a full mix between the two worlds is a burden IMHO.

Comment: Every time I work with C++ I get more and more convinced that it sucks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are willing to go the lazy way I would suggest using a tool to generate C# wrapper for your C++ classes. And of course *the* tool for generating such a wrapper is [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)

For more information, see my old answer to [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682966/looking-for-tutorial-or-basic-information-to-get-me-started-on-implementing-c-c/13683498#13683498)

Comment: I'm accepting your answer for the SWIG suggestion. though we ended up using P/Invoke to a C Wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, in C++ the calling conventions for methods in classes are quite messy.  At the level of the .LIB files that are used by the linker, the function names get "decorated" (see e.g. [Name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)).  Also, the layout of class variables in memory is presumably different between all the different implementations of C++ compared to C#, which is why [Interop Marshaling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eaw10et3.aspx) is such a big topic. So my guess is that Microsoft judged that there are too many low level issues, and hence too hard, to make it worthwile.

I've used both P/Invoke and COM objects to link my C# to C++, but I haven't used C++/CLI.  I've been dabbling in COM for years, and it's very much like it's own language.  So if you've never done any COM I think you're right that it's not worth learning it at this stage.  If a C++/CLI would let you interface to the objects, rather than having to squeeze everything through a C interface, then I think you're right that it'll be the best route.